# What's wrong with this circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, proteus, not-gate, vcc

Hello stack community!

I've just started to learn about logical gates for my university course.
I'm trying to design and run a simple circuit with not gates in Proteus as below:

[image]

But I'm facing with this error message as I try to run it:

[image]

I would appreciate if anyone can help me figure out what the problem is? Or Is there any correct form of  this?

Comment: Most of the logic gates have shorts from input to output. In addition, it looks like the power supply rail is shorted to ground.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Problems:

- 1 and 2. Short circuits between V+ and V-.
- 3, 4, 5 & 6. Short circuits between inverter inputs and outputs.
- 7 and 8. LEDs with no current limiting resistors.

It looks like you copied the outline of a hex-inverter chip into your schematic. (That was wrong.)

---

Tip for future questions:

- Turn off the grid before taking a screengrab.
- Screengrab on the computer rather than take a photo.
- Crop the image.

Comment: Very informative. thanks for your insights. But in the last part what do you mean by "LEDs with no current limiting resistors"?

Comment: I'm presuming that D1 and D2 are indicator LEDs. If you are driving real LEDs from real logic gates then you need a series current limiting resistor in each. See what I've written [here](http://lednique.com/electrical-theory-basics/ohms-law-and-resistor-calculation/) for example.

Comment: I would move your 3,4,5 and 6 dots to the wires on the outputs of the gates, rather than the power and ground busses.  The OP should leave the outputs of unused gates unconnected.

Comment: @Peter, I've deleted the editable image already. I don't think that's going to be the biggest problem!

Comment: @Transistor Depends on what logic chips you're using. If this is a 74xx or 74LSxx you can leave off the limiting resistor since they can't drive more than a few milliamps. If it's a 74HCTxx or a 4000-series chip, you need that limit resistor.

Answer (score 0):

You have not only short-circuited the gate inputs and outputs but also the power supply.

In my opinion, a  little practical experience would stand you in good stead.

To start with, you would do well to get hands-on experience with gate logic by using switches and lamps.

[image]

[image]

That would also help you understand how to wire up a circuit.

Later you could try your hand with ICs.